# iOS accessibility doesn't recognize anything on the screen

Tags: ios, accessibility

I'm trying to make my app accessible (use voice-over properly).

It works just fine in the first screen (login), but after the login no element gets the accessibility focus. It seems to be stuck.

Accessibility inspector's audit gives me this issue for all of the "should-be-accessible" elements in the screen:

> This element appears to display text that should be represented using the accessibility API

When pressing the question mark I get:

> Determine if any part of the content should be exposed as separate accessibility children

Does anybody have an idea? Did you get this warning?

**P.S.**

Apologize in advance, but I can't share my code because of security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem.

Apparently, i've added another view after the login and then animated it off screen, but did not remove from superview.

It caused the app to lose accessibility focus (the focus was on the status bar only).

After removing the view, my app got the accessibility focus again.

My lesson from this problem - remove unnecessary views!

P.S
It's legacy code - wasn't written by me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow three things :

1. You can all the view hierarchy and check whether **accessibilityElements** are properly set or not.
2. Unnecessary views **isAccessibilityElement** property should be set as false.
3. remove Unnecessary views.

Comment: I have a similar problem. 
Accessibility inspector gives warning that potentially inaccessible text. But using the debug view hierarchy - I see nothing in the highlighted (by inspector) area.  Is there some other way to debug such warnings?